# Send special character in SOAP request

Tags: c#, winforms, soap

I am encountering issue sending a SOAP request containing special char to a Web Service. I have a WinForm textbox where user input text such as "1€" for instance. Then I call a WS method which aims to store the data into database.

I implemented the IClientMessageInspector in order to intercept the 
 SOAP inbound/outbound messages, and noticed that the string sent to server is "1▒" :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:MYWebService#insertData</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <q1:insertData xmlns:q1="urn:MYWebService">
      <note xsi:type="xsd:string">1▒</note>
    </q1:insertData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Therefore data stored in database table is "1?".

I did many tries, such as using WebUtility.HtmlEncode without success. I am wondering whether I have to do an action on client side or server one. Can you please advise me about any suggestion to follow?

Answer (score 1):

What was the HtmlEncode returning for you? I would suspect something like

```
<note xsi:type="xsd:string">1&euro;</note>
```

should have some effect.

Comment: The problem is that applying HtmlEncode does not have effect : the method returns "1€" string value, then the characters sent through Soap request remains "1▒"

Comment: Have you tried using `&euro;` in place of the symbol? I'll try running the code when I get back to my dev machine. And out of curiosity, what happens when you call it with the symbol itself without `HtmlEncode`

Comment: When I send "1&euro;" (without any encoding), the Soap request sends <note xsi:type="xsd:string">1&amp;euro;</note> and using HtmlEncode the request is <note xsi:type="xsd:string">1&amp;amp;euro;</note>

Comment: The call of the WS method with and without the HtmlEncode has no differences when the symbol itself is used.